# Problem with clone existing angular project

Tags: angular, git, ngx-international-phone-number

I had cloned an angular project to my new computer and run npm install but still I face the next problem

```
Module '"../../../../../node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/ngx-intl-tel-input"' has no exported member 'TooltipLabel'.
```

this is my import in the component:

```
import { SearchCountryField, TooltipLabel, CountryISO, PhoneNumberFormat } from "ngx-intl-tel-input";
```

and here is my app.module:

`import { NgxIntlTelInputModule } from "ngx-intl-tel-input";`

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NgxIntlTelInputModule,
        ...
```

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "seatback-plus-app",
  "version": "1.2.22",
  
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular-material-components/moment-adapter": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/youtube-player": "^11.0.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@zoomus/websdk": "^1.8.3",
    "android-versions": "^1.6.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.20",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.2.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "cordova-common": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-serve": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "elementtree": "^0.1.7",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.15",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "ng-image-slider": "^2.5.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^9.0.1",
    "node-properties-parser": "0.0.2",
    "nopt": "^5.0.0",
    "properties-parser": "^0.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

this problem don't occur on my old computer, what do I missing?
I checked the angular and cli version and they are the same in both computers

Comment: Can you share your package.json file. This issue has been removed in the v3.1.1 version of the ngx-intl-tel-input package.

Comment: i shared my package.json in the question

Answer (score 0):

I bet your version of angular is not the same on your old computer as on your new one.

You should read the documentation and update the dependency  according to your version of angular.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-intl-tel-input

- Check how you import the dependency.
- And check angular examples.

[image]